# Cannot enforce memory limits in SLURM

Tags: hpc, slurm

I am using Slurm on a single node (control and compute) and I cannot seem to correctly limit memory. The script seems to call SBATCH with small memory values (3G), but I see values in top that exceed 25G. Sacct gives me the correct values:

```
squeue -o "%C %m"
CPUS MIN_MEMORY
2 3G
```

This is my slurm.conf:

```
#
SlurmctldHost=schopenhauer
#
#DisableRootJobs=NO
#EnforcePartLimits=NO
#Epilog=
#EpilogSlurmctld=
#FirstJobId=1
#MaxJobId=999999
#GresTypes=
#GroupUpdateForce=0
#GroupUpdateTime=600
#JobFileAppend=0
#JobRequeue=1
#JobSubmitPlugins=1
#KillOnBadExit=0
#LaunchType=launch/slurm
#Licenses=foo*4,bar
#MailProg=/bin/mail
#MaxJobCount=5000
#MaxStepCount=40000
#MaxTasksPerNode=128
MpiDefault=none
#MpiParams=ports=#-#
#PluginDir=
#PlugStackConfig=
#PrivateData=jobs
#ProctrackType=proctrack/cgroup
ProctrackType=proctrack/linuxproc
#Prolog=
#PrologFlags=
#PrologSlurmctld=
#PropagatePrioProcess=0
#PropagateResourceLimits=
#PropagateResourceLimitsExcept=
#RebootProgram=
ReturnToService=1
#SallocDefaultCommand=
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurmctld.pid
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurmd
SlurmUser=slurm
#SlurmdUser=root
#SrunEpilog=
#SrunProlog=
StateSaveLocation=/var/spool/slurmd
SwitchType=switch/none
#TaskEpilog=
TaskPlugin=task/affinity
TaskPluginParam=Sched
#TaskProlog=
#TopologyPlugin=topology/tree
#TmpFS=/tmp
#TrackWCKey=no
#TreeWidth=
#UnkillableStepProgram=
#UsePAM=0
#
#
# TIMERS
#BatchStartTimeout=10
#CompleteWait=0
#EpilogMsgTime=2000
#GetEnvTimeout=2
#HealthCheckInterval=0
#HealthCheckProgram=
InactiveLimit=0
KillWait=30
#MessageTimeout=10
#ResvOverRun=0
MinJobAge=300000
#OverTimeLimit=0
SlurmctldTimeout=120
SlurmdTimeout=300
#UnkillableStepTimeout=60
#VSizeFactor=0
Waittime=0
#
#
# SCHEDULING
#DefMemPerCPU=0
#MaxMemPerCPU=0
#SchedulerTimeSlice=30
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SelectType=select/cons_tres
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core
#
#
# JOB PRIORITY
#PriorityFlags=
#PriorityType=priority/basic
#PriorityDecayHalfLife=
#PriorityCalcPeriod=
#PriorityFavorSmall=
#PriorityMaxAge=
#PriorityUsageResetPeriod=
#PriorityWeightAge=
#PriorityWeightFairshare=
#PriorityWeightJobSize=
#PriorityWeightPartition=
#PriorityWeightQOS=
#
#
# LOGGING AND ACCOUNTING
#AccountingStorageEnforce=0
#AccountingStorageHost=
AccountingStorageLoc=/var/log/slurm/slurm_jobacct.log
#AccountingStoragePass=
#AccountingStoragePort=
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/filetxt
#AccountingStorageUser=
AccountingStoreJobComment=YES
ClusterName=cluster
#DebugFlags=
#JobCompHost=
JobCompLoc=/var/log/slurm/slurm_jobcomp.log
#JobCompPass=
#JobCompPort=
JobCompType=jobcomp/filetxt
#JobCompUser=
#JobContainerType=job_container/none
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/linux
SlurmctldDebug=info
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurm/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=debug5
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm/slurmd.log
#SlurmSchedLogFile=
#SlurmSchedLogLevel=
#
#
# POWER SAVE SUPPORT FOR IDLE NODES (optional)
#SuspendProgram=
#ResumeProgram=
#SuspendTimeout=
#ResumeTimeout=
#ResumeRate=
#SuspendExcNodes=
#SuspendExcParts=
#SuspendRate=
#SuspendTime=
#
#
# COMPUTE NODES
NodeName=schopenhauer CPUs=128 Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=2 CoresPerSocket=32 ThreadsPerCore=2 RealMemory=500000 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=short Nodes=schopenhauer Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

Did I misunderstand something? Why does it say minimum memory when I want to make that minimum and maximum as well?

EDIT: I just noticed by setting required memory to a larger one that this doesn't work as a minimum either i.e. many tasks were started even though there was enough RAM for only 12 of them (I requested 40G and I have 500G). Is this the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slurm controls memory through the Linux `cgroup` functionality. You need to set `TaskPlugin=task/cgroup` in `slurm.conf` (Cf. https://slurm.schedmd.com/cgroups.html) and `ConstrainRAMSpace=yes` in `cgroup.conf` (Cf. https://slurm.schedmd.com/cgroup.conf.html). Then the memory requested by jobs with `--mem` or `--mem-per-cpu` becomes effectively a hard limit in addition to being a resource request.

The `-m` option of gives the memory requested by the job. As a request, it is considered a minimum requirement. But if you configure `cgroup` it effectively also becomes the maximum.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed that it isn't a minimum requirement either (look at edit). Is this also related to cgroup?

Comment: Indeed, SelectTypeParameters must be set to CR_CPU_Memory rather than CR_Core for memory to be considered a consumable resource. Otherwise Slurm just makes sure jobs land on nodes that have more installed memory than requested, rather than having enough unallocated memory than requested

Answer (score -1):

I don't think slurm enforces memory or cpu usage. It's just there as indication what you think your job's usage will be. To set binding memory you could use ulimit, something like `ulimit -v 3G` at the beginning of your script.

Just know that this will likely cause problems with your program as it actually requires the amount of memory it requests, so it won't finish succesfully.

Comment: I was thinking about that, especially since I cannot understand the mechanism of enforcing that without some super sudo privileges, but then there is so much talk in Slurm documentation that makes no sense. Like errors that arise when Slurm doesn't give them enough memory, or unused memory when your tasks uses less than it reserves.